# I need to check if a row is already in the target worksheet, and if it is i don't want it to copy over and create duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Copy_Amazon()
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Dim tgt As Worksheet
    Dim filterRange As Range
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim DestLastRow As Long
    
    Set src = Workbooks("AMZN COMBINED.xlsm").Worksheets("AMZN")
    Set tgt = Workbooks("Archive_Dispatched.xlsx").Worksheets("Amazon")

    ' turn off any autofilters that are already set
    src.AutoFilterMode = False
 
    ' find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = src.Range("A" & src.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' the range that we are auto-filtering (all columns)
    Set filterRange = src.Range("A1 :O" & lastRow)

    ' the range we want to copy (only columns we want to copy)
    ' in this case we are copying country from column A
    ' we set the range to start in row 2 to prevent copying the header
    Set copyRange = src.Range("A2:O" & lastRow)

    ' filter range based on column J
    filterRange.AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="D"

    ' copy the visible cells to our target range
    DestLastRow = tgt.Cells(tgt.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy tgt.Range("A" & DestLastRow)
    
    'Turn off Auto Filter again
    src.AutoFilterMode = False

End Sub
```

As stated in the question i am able to copy and paste rows from source to target sheet using autofilter but i am trying to only bring in new rows or changed rows, any idea on how i can do this?

Comment: Use `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` to test if the common identifier(s) are already present on the target sheet.

Comment: @BigBen Could you possibly provide an in code example of how id use range.find?

Comment: @Gmx5000 feel free to google either of those items.  there are many many examples on how to use it.

Comment: How do you identify a duplicate record? Is it that all of the cells in the row match, or is there a uniquely identifying key field. How many records on average does a source sheet have?

Comment: @basodre all of the cells in the row would need to match, because sometime only just a cell is changed and i would need that record. This sheet is about 100 rows on average

Comment: why not use the new Filter formula, instead of VBA? P.S: its available in O365 subscription